# SSRS throws error on IP swap

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

We have swapped SQL existing IP of working DB server for new server and after that SQL reports when executed from web application throws error. Application work fine for CRUD operation; its reports fails.

But as we swap back IP to old server it works fine.

NOTE: We made windows firewall off.

Error log - Report View System Error for Report "ReportName" :- System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond XXXX:80 at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress) at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Int32 timeout, Exception& exception) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Internal.Soap.ReportingServices2005.Execution.RSExecutionConnection.GetSecureMethods() at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Internal.Soap.ReportingServices2005.Execution.RSExecutionConnection.IsSecureMethod(String methodname) at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Internal.Soap.ReportingServices2005.Execution.RSExecutionConnection.SetConnectionSSLForMethod(String methodname) at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Internal.Soap.ReportingServices2005.Execution.RSExecutionConnection.ProxyMethodInvocation.Execute[TReturn](RSExecutionConnection connection, ProxyMethod1 initialMethod, ProxyMethod1 retryMethod)

Comment: Check your report data source connection settings. If it is a shared data source stored on the report server you just have to update the connection string of the data source

Comment: Thanks for looking at issue. It's not shared data source and connection string is using the IP is used now by current DB server and once IP is swapped to new server will continue pointing to required DB. Did I missed anything from you response.